# Access function inside class from a function that is located in another public function

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to access the function `file_get_contents_curl`. from fucntion `get_facebook_details()`.

```
class frontend {

    public function file_get_contents_curl($domain) {

    }

    public function get_all_seo_details() {
      require_once('details-functions.php');
      $facebook_details = get_facebook_details($cur_domain);
    }

}
```

details-functions.php

```
function get_facebook_details() {
  $result = file_get_contents_curl('http://graph.facebook.com/'.$username);
  //.... some more code
}
```

I tried:

```
$result = self::file_get_contents_curl('http://graph.facebook.com/'.$username);
```

**Fatal error: Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active.**

```
$result = $this->file_get_contents_curl('http://graph.facebook.com/'.$username);
```

**non-object this error**

```
$result = frontend::file_get_contents_curl('http://graph.facebook.com/'.$username);
```

**Strict standards: Non-static method frontend::file_get_contents_curl() should not be called statically**

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_get_contents_curl()**

Comment: Well first of all, you should get rid of the require statement in the method's body. Why are you doing that anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write the function as static. `self::` can be used to to call function statically. If you don't write the function as static then can use `$this->` to call the function. Try something like this

```
class frontend {
    public static function file_get_contents_curl($domain) {

    }

    public static function get_all_seo_details() {
       require_once('details-functions.php');
       $facebook_details = get_facebook_details($cur_domain);
   }
}
```

Comment: use `$this` if function is not `static`

Comment: This is what I have used before, when function was `NOT STATIC`.

Comment: You write function inside function. I modified your code here: `class frontend {
    public function file_get_contents_curl($domain) {
        echo $domain;
    }
    public function get_all_seo_details() {

        $facebook_details = $this->get_facebook_details();
        echo $facebook_details;
    }
    function get_facebook_details() {
        $result = $this->file_get_contents_curl('http://graph.facebook.com/');
    }
}
$fe = new frontend;
echo $fe->get_all_seo_details();`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make those methods static if you wish to call them statically outside of the class.

```
public static function file_get_contents_curl(){ ... }
```